# NLP preprocessing remove all words in string not found in my list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, nlp, preprocessor

I've made a list of `important_words` and a have a dataframe that has a column `df['reviews']`, that has one `string` of `review text` per row (thousands of rows). I want to update the 'reviews' by removing everything that is not in the `important_words` `list` from the string, like the opposite of having `stop words`, so that I am only left with the `important_words` per every `review` (row) in the df.

Also, later in my starter code I tokenize and normalize the column of `df[reviews]`, it seems like applying to this column should make everything easier, since punctuation removal and lowercasing has also been applied. I'll try which ever method someone can share, thanks.

```
important_words = [actor, action, awesome]

   df['reviews'][1] = 'The actor, in the action movie was awesome'
   df['reviews'][2] = 'The action movie was not good'
   ....
   df['tokenized_normalized_reviews'][1] = [the,actor,in,the,action,movie,was,awesome]
   df['tokenized_normalized_reviews'][2] = [the, action, movie, was, not, good]

I want: 
df['review_important_words'][1] = 'actor, action, awesome' 
df['review_important_words'][2] = 'action' 
< either str or applied to the tokenized column>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['reviews'] = df['reviews'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word in (important_words)]))
```

You can do it like this using pandas. Applying the function would make it work for all the elements of this column.

Comment: Yes I removed the `not` and it works ( I only want those words). Maybe you can edit your post for others. Thanks!

Comment: @Gazoo Ah yes. Corrected